# Google Sites File Attachment Date and Time

Tags: google-classic-sites, date

I live in the Central Time Zone.  When I attach a file in my Google Site, it shows Pacific Time for the Attachment Time.  Is there anyway to have it show Central Time?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a per-site setting, but a user setting (as a user of Sites). Follow these instructions to change your time-zone preference:

- Go to http://sites.google.com (where you see the list of your sites)
- Click on the settings (cog) button and choose 'User settings'.
- The User settings page has a dropdown for choosing your time-zone. Change it to 'Central'.

From this point forward, all times within Google Sites should be presented in Central Time. Of course, other people might decide to look at your Site using a different time-zone, but that's, of course, their choice.